# Entity hibernate implement serialized

Tags: hibernate, entity, serializable

I used to read a coding best practice is the entity of hibernate should not implement

> java.io.Serializable

.

My idea is just for better performance, to avoid compiler processing something for the entity. And we should use DTO serialized to communicate client and server instead.

Is it right?

Thank so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a best practice at all, and implementing serializable or not doesn't have any impact on performance. If you want to be able to serialize your entities, make them implement Serializable. If you don't want to, then don't make them implement Serializable. It's as simple as that.

Using a DTO when the entity itself contains the adequate information is rather viewed as an anti-pattern than viewed as a best practice.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Hibernate POJOs are not serializable. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate POJOs are not serializable. This is not a question of best practice or performance. It simply does not work. That's why.

You won't get any compiler errors when you declare the POJOs as serializable. But at execution time when you try to serialize and deserialize the objects you might get a exception.

The problem appears for example when you use GWT and you send data between the client and the server. This fails with Hibernate POJOs just because they can't be serialized. See the [description of GWT with Hibernate](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate) in the chapter "Why Hibernate objects can't be understood when they reach the browser world" (a bit before the middle of the page) for a more detailed exception.

Comment: Just because Hibernate POJOs can't be used with GWT doesn't mean they're not serializable. GWT is a very special environment, where Java code is compiled to JavaScript and run in the browser. Normal applications, where the client is a Java application, can serialize Hibernate POJOs just fine. I've been on several projects where Hibernate POJOs were serialized and sent over the network to a Swing application.

Comment: GWT indeed _is_ a special environment, but it is exactly the serialization of Hibernate objects which does not work. That's why the general recommendation not to implement Serializable is correct and why I disagree with your answer. When a class implements Serializable it should works always and not only sometimes.

Comment: It does not work because the GWT support for Java is limited. Even non-serializable classes are incompaticle with GWT. Even some Guava classes, from Google, are incompatible with GWT, from Google. Java serialization of Hibernate POJOs does work fine, always. GWT is not Java.